# Ноль в конце данных ajax запроса?

Tags: php, wordpress

echo добавляет в конце 0, при ошибке и при правильной работе. Как его убрать?
Вот код

```
if ($formname == 'zapis') {

$name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
$city = trim(strip_tags($_POST['city']));
$phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
$email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$title_event = trim(strip_tags($_POST['event_title']));
$date_start = trim(strip_tags($_POST['event_datestart']));
$id_event = trim(strip_tags($_POST['id_event']));
$id_company = trim(strip_tags($_POST['id_company']));
$name_company = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name_company']));

if(empty($title_event) or empty($date_start) or empty($name_company)) {
    echo 'Ошибка, перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте ещё раз';
    wp_die(); }

if(empty($email)) {
       echo 'Ошибка, введите Email';
    wp_die(); }
    if(empty($city)) {
        echo 'Ошибка, введите Город';
     wp_die(); }
     if(empty($phone)) {
        echo 'Ошибка, введите Телефон';
     wp_die(); }
     if(empty($name)) {
        echo 'Ошибка, введите Имя';
     wp_die(); }


if ( ! filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
echo 'Ошибка, Плохой Email';
wp_die(); }

if ( ! filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ) {
    echo 'Ошибка, Не верно указан телефон';
    wp_die(); }

$result = subscriber_insert_item($name, $phone, $email, $city, $ip_user, $id_event, $title_event, $date_start, $id_company, $name_company);

  if($result){
      echo 'Вы успешно записались';
  }else {
      echo 'Ошибка, попробуйте ещё раз';
  }

  //wp_die();
```

}

Функция записи

```
function subscriber_insert_item($name, $phone, $email, $city, $ip_user, $id_event, $title_event, $date_start, $id_company, $name_company) {
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'subscribers';

// подготавливаем данные   
$name = esc_sql($name);
$phone = esc_sql($phone);
$email = esc_sql($email);
$city = esc_sql($city);
$ip_user = esc_sql($ip_user);
$id_event = esc_sql($id_event);
$title_event = esc_sql($title_event);
$date_start = esc_sql($date_start);
$id_company = esc_sql($id_company);
$name_company = esc_sql($name_company);
$new ='new';

// вставляем строку в таблицу
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name, array(
    'name' => $name,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'email' => $email,
    'city' => $city,
    'date_reg' => date("Y-m-d H:i", time()),
    'ip_user' => $ip_user,
    'id_event' => $id_event,
    'title_event' => $title_event,
    'date_start' => $date_start,
    'id_company' => $id_company,
    'name_company' => $name_company,
    'new' => $new,
        )
);

return true; 


 wp_die();
// exit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, не `echo`, а `wp_die()`. Эта функция предназначена для вывода дополнительной информации при завершении скрипта. Используйте просто `die()`. А ещё лучше - `send_json_success()` и `send_json_error()`.